# torch_geometric.nn radius_graph example giving AttributeError

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

when trying to execute the example code for `radius_graph` from `torch_geometric`
i get the following error:

```py
File "C:\Users\nico_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\nn\pool\__init__.py", line 210, in radius_graph
    return torch_cluster.radius_graph(x, r, batch, loop, max_num_neighbors,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'radius_graph'
```

the code giving the error is https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.nn.pool.radius_graph.html#torch_geometric.nn.pool.radius_graph

```py
import torch
from torch_geometric.nn import radius_graph

x = torch.Tensor([[-1, -1], [-1, 1], [1, -1], [1, 1]])
batch = torch.tensor([0, 0, 0, 0])
edge_index = radius_graph(x, r=1.5, batch=batch, loop=False)
```

i tried also to import `from torch_geometric.nn.pool` but gives the same error as if it doesn't find the funcion.

I'm using python 3.8 with VScode in windows 11

edit:
I tried setting a venv in pycharm just for this project and now the problem has shifted to installing torch_cluster (same problem both for torch 1.13 and 2.0): after installing torch_geometric 2.3.0 i type the command

`pip install pyg_lib torch_scatter torch_sparse torch_cluster torch_spline_conv -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cpu.html`

(with the last part `torch-xxx+cpu.html` 1.13 or 2.0 when trying with torch 1.13 or 2.0, both didn't work) it gives me this error:

```
Looking in links: https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.13.0+cpu.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyg_lib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyg_lib
```

thank you so far for the help

Comment: I ran the snippet of code you have supplied, and didn't face any error. `edge_index = tensor([], size=(2, 0), dtype=torch.int64)`. Ran on Windows 10 using python 3.8.
Verify that you do have the package torch_cluster. If not, then `pip install torch-cluster` and try to run your code again.

Comment: it is probably a dependencies issue, i'll try with a venv just for this project in pycharm, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling everything solved the problem as always, the working dependencies are torch -> 2.0.0+cpu, torch_gemetric -> 2.3.0, torch_cluster -> 1.6.1+pt20cpu, python -> 3.8